# Errors with django urls

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-templates, django-views

I'm getting an error 404 when i click the link on django, i have spent so much time trying to see what i'm doing wrong but no luck.

here is my index.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title>Page Title</title>
</head>
<body>

<h1>{{title}}</h1>

{% for obj in object_list %}
{% url "detail" id=obj.id %}
<a href = '{{obj.get_absolute_url}}'> {{obj.title}}</a><br/>
{{obj.content}} <br/>
{{obj.timestamp}} <br/>
{{obj.updated}} <br/>
{{obj.id}} <br/>


{% endfor %}    
</body>
</html>
```

This is my urls.py

```
from django.conf.urls import url
from django.contrib import admin

from .views import (
    post_list,
    post_create,
    post_detail,
    post_update,
    post_delete,
    )

urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^$', post_list),
    url(r'^create/$', post_create),
    url(r'^detail/(?P<id>\d+)/$', post_detail, name='detail'),
    url(r'^update/$', post_update),
    url(r'^delete/$', post_delete),

]
```

This is my views.py

```
from django.http import HttpResponse
from django.shortcuts import render, get_object_or_404

from .models import Post

# Create your views here.

def post_create(request):
    return HttpResponse("<h1>Create</h1>")

def post_detail(request, id): # retreive
    instance = get_object_or_404(Post, id=id)
    context = {
        "title": instance.title,
        "instance": instance,
    }
    return render(request, "post_detail.html", context) 

def post_list(request): # list of posts
    queryset = Post.objects.all
    context = {
        "title": "List",
        "object_list": queryset,
    }
    return render(request, "index.html", context) 

def post_update(request):
    return HttpResponse("<h1>Update</h1>")  

def post_delete(request):
    return HttpResponse("<h1>Delete</h1>")
```

and this is my models.py

```
from __future__ import unicode_literals

from django.db import models

# Create your models here.
class Post(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length = 120)
    content = models.TextField()
    updated = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True, auto_now_add = False )
    timestamp = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=False, auto_now_add = True )

    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.title


    def __str__(self):
        return self.title

    def get_absolute_url(self):
        return "/posts/%s" %(self.id)
```

Comment: Why not use `'{% url "detail" id=obj.id %}'` for your `href`?

Comment: That seems to work but i don't know why

Comment: As far as I know this is the standard way to wire up views in your templates, I don't quite follow what you were trying to achieve the other way. Glad it works though! Maybe read up on the template tags documentation, or try rephrasing your question if you have a good reason for wanting to do it the other way.

Comment: i was following tutorial online and that is how the tutor did. but unfortunately it didn't work on my side. spend so much time trying to see what was wrong.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `get_absolute_url` method returns URLs in the form `/posts/<id>` but your urlconf is expecting `/posts/detail/<id>`.

Instead of hard-coding a URL like that in the method, you should use the `reverse` functionality:

```
from django.urls import reverse
...
def get_absolute_url(self):
    return reverse('detail', kwargs={'id': self.id})
```